# Stop URL adding to Existing URL

Tags: html, magento, url, hyperlink

I am trying to link to an external site, but everytime I do so the external website is getting added onto the url of the existing site I am on. Therefore making the website address invalid. I'm sure i've come across this before and fixed it, but I can't remember / find the solution this time round. Any ideas?

```
<a href=“http://www.google.com”><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/logo.jpg') ?>" alt="" id=“logo” /></a>
```

This coding will, for example take me to the following:
http://www.mywebsite.com/http://www.google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using funny quotes which are not valid in HTML. As a result the URL is appended to the current URL. Change `“` and `”` to `"`

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
```

Comment: Thank you!! This did the trick. I didn't even know it was possible to change the " thanks again!!